# Unity - Reschedule on Device Restart is not working

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play

I'm using:
Mobile Notifications - v2.1.1
Unity - 2021.3.15f1

Reschedule notifications flag in Unity doesn't work.

Class

```
public class NotificationManager : MonoBehaviour {

    private readonly string channelId = "daily_gift_channel";

    void Start() {
        var channel = new AndroidNotificationChannel() {
            Id = channelId,
            Name = "Daily Gift",
            Importance = Importance.Default,
            Description = "Daily Gift Notifications",
        };
        AndroidNotificationCenter.RegisterNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    public void requestNotification() {

        if ((Utils.getAndroidVersion() < 33 && Utils.getAndroidVersion() >= 28) || 
            Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission("android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS")) {
            AndroidNotificationCenter.CancelAllScheduledNotifications();
            AndroidNotificationCenter.CancelAllDisplayedNotifications();
            scheduleNotification();
        } else {
            PermissionCallbacks callbacks = new PermissionCallbacks();
            callbacks.PermissionGranted += (string permissionName) => {
                scheduleNotification();
            };
            Permission.RequestUserPermission("android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS", callbacks);
        }
    }

    private void scheduleNotification() {
        DateTime deliveryTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5);

        var notification = new AndroidNotification();
        notification.Title = "title";
        notification.Text = "text";
        notification.ShouldAutoCancel = true;
        notification.FireTime = deliveryTime;
    AndroidNotificationCenter.SendNotification(notification, channelId);
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.unity3d.player"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application>
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
                  android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector"
                  android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data 
                android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" 
                android:value="true" />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I've searching the similar issues but have not found anything useful.
Please help to fiand a root cause.

I've checked flag **Reschedule on Device Restart** and expect the notifications will appear after reboot. Have I do something except this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 3 days of research I have found the root cause.

In my game I was using [Google Mobile Ads Unity Plugin v8.5.1](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/releases) and commenting the line `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.0.0' // Assets/GoogleMobileAds/Editor/GoogleMobileAdsDependencies.xml:7` in overriden `gradleTemplate.gradle` file have made notifications appear after device reboot.

**Summary:** Decrease Google Mobile Ads Android SDK to 21.3.0 by using [Google Mobile Ads Unity Plugin v7.4.1](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/releases/tag/v7.4.1) cause with higher versions it doesn't work. Seems it's a bug on Google or Unity side.

By the way ticket created against Google https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/issues/2895